# On the evaluation of the integral $\int_{-\frac{b}{a}}^{\frac{1-b}{a}}\log\left(ax+b\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\mathrm{d}x$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

Let $x\in(0,1)$ be a random variable that follows a truncated normal distribution with density 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}D}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)                 & \text{, if}\:\:0<x<1           \\
      0 & \text{, otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
where $D=\Phi\left(\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)$ (let $\Phi$ denote the cdf of the standard normal distribution).

I am interested in evaluating the integral
$$
I = \int_{0}^{1}g(x)f(x)\mathrm{d}x,
$$
where $g(x)=\log(x)$, $x>0$, is the neperian logarithm, i.e. the integral
$$
I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}D}\int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)\mathrm{d}x,
$$
which, using the substitution $u=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$, is rewritten as follows
$$
I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}D}\int_{-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}}^{\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma}}\log\left(\sigma u+\mu\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)\mathrm{d}u.
$$

I know that this couldn't be given in a closed form. If this makes any difference, I want to use this for a practical application, so if there could be a numerical approximation with some given accuracy, that would suit me, but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Are your integrals supposed to be from $0$ to $\infty$ or from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ as you have them?

Comment: @SarthakC I would like to see what happens when we it's from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but if that helps, let's suppose for now that it's from $0$ to $\infty$. In the former case the result is complex, right?

Comment: What is log (-1) for you? Which branch do you take?

Comment: @Ian, well, it's imaginary but I would like to see how we work in this case. Let's make things simpler. Please let me edit my question. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @SarthakC, thanks for the comment; I edited my question. Let's make the limits to be $0$ and $+\infty$.

Comment: do you have certain limits in minf? like small/big $\mu,\sigma$?

Comment: @tired, for now, I cannot think of such limits.

Comment: @tired, I have made some major edits in my original question. What I really need is the integral from $0$ to $1$, granted that $f$ is the pdf of a truncated normal distribution. I hope that it's more clear now. I have also started a bounty.Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Ian, I have made some additional assumptions; could you let me know about your thoughts on this? Actually, what I want to compute is the mean value of the quantity $\log(x)$, when $x$ is distributed as a truncated normal variable in $(0,1)$. Do you think it's a meaningful assumption/formulation? Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Approach**: EDIT: I'm not too fond of this one, the second one seems better to me.I'll write $a = -\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$ and $b = \frac{1-\mu}{\sigma}$ and assume $\mu \neq 0$.

$$I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}D}\int_{a}^{b}\log\left(\sigma u+\mu\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)\mathrm{d}u.$$

If $\mu \neq 0$, we can rewrite $\log(\sigma u + \mu) = \log(\frac{1}{\mu}) + \log(1+\frac{\sigma}{\mu}u)$. I'll denote $c := \frac{\sigma}{\mu}$. We can split this up into two integrals $I = I_1 + I_2$, where

$$ I_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}D} \int_{a}^{b} -\log(\mu) \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)\mathrm{d}u = \frac{-\log(\mu)}{D}\text{erf}(u)\Big|_{a}^{b},$$
and
$$I_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}D}\int_{a}^{b}\log\left(1+ cu\right)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)\mathrm{d}u.$$
Here I see two possiblites to continue: Plugging in the taylor expansion for $\log(1+cu)$ or the taylor expansion for $\exp(u)$. I'll begin with the former. Exchanging summation and integral (which i'm not yet sure is legal), and integrating by parts we obtain
\begin{align}
I_2 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}D}\int_{a}^{b}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} (cu)^n\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)\mathrm{d}u \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}D}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{a}^{b} \frac{(-c)^n}{n} u^n\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}u^2\right)\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{1}{D}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-c)^n \left[ \frac{u^n}{n}\text{erf}(u)\Big|_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b}u^{n-1}\text{erf}(u) \mathrm{d}u\right]\\
\end{align}

Looking up the last integral in [this integral table](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf) (page 5, number 7)
, we obtain

\begin{align}
I_2 = \frac{1}{D}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-c)^n}{\sqrt{\pi}(n+1)} \left[ e^{-u^2}\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-k+1)} u^{n-2k} - (1-j)\Gamma\left(l+\frac{1}{2}\right)\text{erf}(u)\right]_{a}^{b}
\end{align}

where $j = 0$ or $j=1$ such that $2l-j = n+1$. Now for the second approach, that yields a much nicer-looking sum.

**Second Approach**:
Starting with

$$I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}D}\int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

I'll expand the exponential function: 
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}D\cdot I &= \int_{0}^{1} \log(x) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n \cdot n!}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2n} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sigma^{2n}\cdot 2^n \cdot n!} \int_{0}^{1} \left(x-\mu\right)^{2n} \log(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sigma^{2n}\cdot 2^n \cdot n!} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}(-\mu)^{2n-k} \int_{0}^{1}x^{k} \log(x) \mathrm{d}x \\
\end{align}

Applying the formula 
$$\int x^{k}\ln x\,dx=\frac{x^{k+1}((k+1)\ln x-1)}{(k+1)^2}$$
we obtain

$$ I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}D} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sigma^{2n}\cdot 2^n \cdot n!} \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}(-\mu)^{2n-k} \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} $$

It's not too hard to see that interchanging integral and sum is allowed using Fubini. We can find yet another representation for $I$: Using the binomial theorem, we see that

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} (xy - \mu)^n \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k}(-\mu)^{2n-k} \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$$

Thus, we can write
\begin{align} I &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}D} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sigma^{2n}\cdot 2^n \cdot n!} \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} (xy - \mu)^n \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&= -\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}D} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{xy - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right) \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\end{align}
Now we have a smooth integrand on our domain. Therefore, it should be possible to obtain good numerical results by applying high-degree 2-dimensional tensor product formulas of univariate Gauss-Legendre Quadrature formulas.

Comment: @nullgeppetto I have added a second approach that yields a nicer-looking sum.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll definitely need some time to look at it, but I'm afraid that even the second sum, which seems really nice, couldn't help me in my practical application. I need to compute it literally, so I cannot see how this could be efficient. What do you think about this aspect? Thanks again :)

Comment: @nullgeppetto I'm not sure how efficient it would be. As you have terms like $\frac{1}{2^n \cdot n!}$ I suppose that in many cases taking the first 10 terms or something may lead to a good approximation (This may however depend on the magnitude of $\sigma$ and $\mu$ too). In the "standard case" $\mu = 0$, $\sigma = 1$ for example, this would converge quite nicely.

Comment: I see. Yes, you have a point. Your approach is nice as a theoretical tool, but I think it would cause numerical troubles :) In any case, I thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: @nullgeppetto I have an idea on how to deal with some numerical troubles, but I'm too tired today to continue working on it now. Maybe you'll hear from me again tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you :) In any case I'll keep the question open for a week; if you like you and have time you could add your thought, I'd really like to read them.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$\int_0^1\log(x)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)^2\right)\mathrm{d}x$$

can be seen as a convolution of $\log(x)$ restricted to the domain $(0,1]$, with a Gaussian, i.e. it is a blurred version of $\log(x)$.

As $\log(x)$ is integrable over $(0,1]$ (which yields $-1$), so is the given integral, for any $\mu,\sigma$.

As a consequence of the central limit theorem, convolution with a Gaussian can be approximated by a succession of convolutions with a uniform filter of appropriate width (the resulting variance is $nw^2/12$). http://oscar6echo.blogspot.be/2012/10/convolve-n-square-pulses-to-gaussian.html.

Also see Wells, W.M.: Efficient synthesis of Gaussian filters by cascaded uniform filters. IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence 8(2), 234–239 (Mar 1986).

The uniform convolutions can be performed analytically, as

$$\int x^{k-1}\ln x\,dx=\frac{x^k(k\ln x-1)}{k^2}.$$

---

Stated differently, you can obtain good estimates of the integral by using the uniform B-spline approximation of the Gaussian, which leads to integrands of the form $\ln xP(x)$.

You find the relevant formula here: http://sepwww.stanford.edu/public/docs/sep105/sergey2/paper_html/node5.html#sergey2_eqn:expl

$$\beta_n(x)=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}k(-1)^k\left(x+\frac{n+1}2-k\right)_+^n$$ where the subscript $_+$ denotes the restriction to positive arguments.

Notice that the approximation is only useful where the Gaussian is significantly nonzero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'd never thought it that way, but it seems that it suits me, since I need it in a practical application and the result should be computationally efficient (I think). However, I don't understand exactly how to apply your approach yet. I assume that the number of successive convolutions with a uniform filter would be a "user-defined" parameter. I also don't get this: "(the resulting variance is $nw/12$)". Could you please elaborate more on the formulation? In the meantime, I'll study your suggestions, but could you confirm what the result would be?Thank you.

Comment: Hi Yves, in my attempts to understand your approach, I found some difficulties, so I edited my question so that I can add your solution after figuring it out. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: @nullgeppetto: the second way to address the question should be easier. You can address this by means of the Fourier transform, and you need to invert $\text{sinc}^n(\omega)$, which gives you a piecewise polynomial that approximates the Gaussian. The computation can certainly be found somewhere on the Web, but I couldn't spot if so far.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ok, but what about the first approach, the one you originally proposed? It seems more elegant to me. Could you continue my original post and help me understand how the last integral should be approximated using the succession of convolutions? Many thanks :)

Comment: @nullgeppetto: they are the same approach, expressed differently. Once you have the polynomial expression, things are easy. Multiple convolution passes will make it more complicated.

Comment: So, my integral should be approximated as this: $I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}D}\int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\beta_n(x)\mathrm{d}x$**?**
What I don't understand is where the Gaussian parameters ($\mu$ and $\sigma^2$) are involved. Apologies for my ignorance, but it seems that I miss something. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nullgeppetto: why did you drop them from the LHS ?

Comment: I did that because I thought that $\beta_n(x)$ approximated the whole Gaussian (its pdf together with the normalization term). So, what you're saying is that $I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\int_0^1\log(x)\beta_n(x)dx$? And what about the mean $\mu$? Should this embedded in the the $\beta_n$ function?

Comment: @nullgeppetto: these are trivial change of variable issues, I shouldn't have to tell you.

Comment: I'm sorry I have to ask, you're right of course, but what I don't understand is what the $\beta_n$ function actually approximates; this still confuses me. Does this approximate the exponential part of the standard normal distribution, i.e., $\beta_n(x)=\exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^2)$, without the normalization term? Again, apologies for bothering you. Thanks for your time.